# Visual Studio new ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 Web API project results in Nuget dependency error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I just updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and installed DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2 from 
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows.

I then created a new project for asp.net core that contains web.api and after Visual Studio started restoring nuget I got the following error:

> Errors in C:\Private\Commercify\Dev\WebApis\Commercify.Catalog.WebApi\project.json
>   Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 supports:
>   - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
>   - netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
>   One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

This is my entire `project.json` I have not changed anything in it yet it contains what Visual Studio generates for a new ASP.NET Core Web API project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0", 
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  }, 
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Opening the project.json file shows a red squiggly on the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0" that says:

> The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version = v1.0

How can I fix this?